# Why does gem persist in installing to ~/.rvm after I've moved to rbenv?

Tags: ruby, rvm, rbenv

I've decided to move away from [rvm](https://rvm.io) to [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) on my personal machine. Followed the rvm removal instructions, installed rbenv and everything looks peachy. After restarting my shell session:

```
$ rbenv global
1.9.3-p0

$ ls .rvm
ls: cannot access .rvm: No such file or directory

$ rbenv exec gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***
```

A completely fresh install in a fresh shell--RVM's long gone. Now, when I install [bundler](http://gembundler.com/)

```
$ rbenv exec gem install bundler
Fetching: bundler-1.0.22.gem (100%)
Successfully installed bundler-1.0.22
1 gem installed

$ rbenv rehash

$ echo $?
0

$ rbenv which bundle
rbenv: bundle: command not found
```

What? Indeed, look at this nonsense:

```
$ ls .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/bundler-1.0.22/
bin  bundler.gemspec  CHANGELOG.md  ISSUES.md  lib  LICENSE  man  Rakefile  README.md  spec  UPGRADING.md
```

Somehow, someway, RVM still has its hooks into me. My `~/.bash*` files are clean and

```
$ cat ~/.gemrc 
gem: --no-ri --no-rdoc
```

I have no system ruby, no globally installed RVM (nothing in `/etc/profile/`, no `/etc/profile.d/rvm.sh` and nothing in `/etc/bash.bashrc`) and I'm at a complete loss.

```
$ gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.11
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2011-10-30 patchlevel 0) [i686-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/blt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /home/blt/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p0/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/blt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /home/blt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0
     - /home/blt/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - "gem" => "--no-ri --no-rdoc"
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

Where else can I look to figure out why gem's configured to install to `~/.rvm`?

Comment: Did you reload your bash session?

Comment: Should have mentioned that. Yes and killed the shell, just for the hell of it. No change.

Comment: So `which rvm` fails, and there are no values for `GEM_HOME, GEM_PATH` ?

Comment: Ah! `which rvm` does fail, but there are indeed values for GEM_HOME and GEM_PATH, pointing into `~/.rvm` for the both of them. I'll update my question with the output of `gem env`.

Comment: Looks like the source of the problem to me.  Fix your Gem environment and rbenv should take over.

Comment: Agreed. Problem is, I'm having a hard time figuring out where my Gem environment is being screwed up.

Comment: Reinstall? I suspect that those are pretty set for life upon installation.

Comment: I have reinstalled. No correction.

Comment: Well... that was all I could think of. Sorry, good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something's clearly rotten on my system; no grepping has turned it up, but tacking

```
unset GEM_HOME
unset GEM_PATH
```

to the end of my `~/.bashrc` made things sane. Horrible hack, though.

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever installed rvm in a system location? Maybe those env vars got into a system-wide shell config.

Try running:

bash -l -x -c 'echo'

This will print bash debugging output so you can see what files are being loaded. It may not show commands inside sourced scripts, depending on your version of bash.

This probably doesn't apply to you, but if it exists, what are the contents of `~/.gemrc` ?

Comment: I'm afraid I've switched personal computers and no longer have access to the environment discussed. Thank you, though.